# How do I interpret interaction coefficients in a temporally lagged regression model?

Tags: regression, time-series, interaction, interpretation

I am running a linear regression on daily price returns and I want to capture the interaction between subsequent returns:

$r_{t+1} = \alpha + \beta_1 r_t + \beta_2 r_{t-1} + \beta_3 r_t \cdot r_{t-1} + \epsilon$

Where $r$ is a geometric return ($p / p_{t-1}$).

Each coefficient is interperable as a linear multiplicative factor of the return.  How can I interpret the meaning of $\beta_3$, the interaction term?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\beta_{3}$ is modeling non-linear effects of $r$ on the future values. Suppose $\beta_{3} > 0$ (everything below is reversed if $\beta_{3} < 0$). In this particular case some things you could interpret are that:

(1) If $r_{t-1} > 0$ then the effect of $r_{t}$ is increased (or moved toward 0 if $\beta_{1} < 0)$.

(2) If $r_{t-1} < 0$ then the effect of $r_{t}$ is decreased (or moved toward 0 if $\beta_{1} < 0$).

(3) If both $r_{t-1}$ and $r_{t}$ have the same sign, then there is a positive effect on $r_{t+1}$.

(4) If $r_{t-1}$ and $r_{t}$ have a different sign, then there is a negative effect on $r_{t+1}$.

The simplest way to display these effects are to, for example, plot the model fitted $r_{t+1}$ against $r_{t}$ with a different line for different values of $r_{t-1}$; $-2,-1,0,1,2$ may be suitable choices (you may want to adjust this grid depending on the scale of $r$). In that case, the first line would be $\beta_{1}r_{t} - 2\beta_{2} -2\beta_{3}r_{t}$ - the second one would be $\beta_{1}r_{t} - \beta_{2} -\beta_{3}r_{t}$, and so on.  This is called an interaction plot - you have to choose a discrete grid of points for one of the interacting variables (I've chosen $r_{t-1}$ here) since it would be impossible to plot the interaction across a continuum. The interpretation may become more clear after making this plot.

Comment: It also helps to rewrite the model as $r_{t+1} = (\alpha + \beta_{2} r_{t-1}) + (\beta_{1} + \beta_{3} r_{t-1}) r_{t}$. This is a simple regression model $r_{t+1} = \alpha' + \beta' r_{t}$ where the absolute term $\alpha'$ and the regression weight $\beta'$ are both linear functions of $r_{t-1}$. $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are often called "simple intercept" and "simple slope", respectively. To choose values for $r_{t-1}$ for the interaction plot, I've often seen people use the mean, and $\pm$ 1 standard deviation.